# Flutter widget positioning in Column

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I have this widget Tree:

- Center

  - Padding

    - Column

      - TextField
      - TextField
      - Text
      - Button
      - SizedBox

        - SvgPicture.asset

And I want to put all widgets except SvgPicture(or SizedBox in which is Picture) to middle of screen and only image to center bottom of screen. MainAxisAlignment of Column is center. Output is: [image]

Image should be at bottom and other widgets in the middle of screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use Spacer to achieve this.
So your column will look like this :

```
Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Spacer(),
                  TextField(),
                  TextField(),
                  Text("Hola"),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Button"),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 70,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: If you add `Scrollable` widget on top of `Column`, `Spacer` will complain about unbound constraints

Comment: That is true indeed, but its not the case in his code i think.

Comment: Its another issue, heppens when trying to use `Spacer` inside `Scrollable` widget. Do you really want to make full screen dialog?

Comment: Thank you guys for help a lot. But how do I manage it in case you mentioned? If my top level widget is for example SingleChildScrollView
Thanks.